# mascara input html com javascript

Tags: javascript, html

boa noite.
tenho este campo com máscara ao digitar o cpf, acontece que se copiar/colar ele não aplica a máscara, só os numeros.

como poderei ter as 2 formas de máscara no imput?

```
function formatar(mascara, documento){
  var i = documento.value.length;
  var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
  var texto = mascara.substring(i)

  if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
            documento.value += texto.substring(0,1);
  }

}

o input:
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" />
```

Comment: Já tentaste com `onpaste` ou `oninput`?

Comment: como assim, no input ou no java?

Comment: No elemento HTML: `onpaste="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" oninput="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)"`

Comment: o copiar/colar não funcionou...

Comment: Você já tentou usar o  Maskedinput: https://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/

Answer (score 1):

O código está comentado e de fácil entendimento

```js
function ValidaCPF(){   

var ao_cpf=document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value ; 
var cpfValido = /^(([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}))$/; 

    if (cpfValido.test(ao_cpf) == false)    { 
 
     ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /\D/g , ""); //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
     
     if (ao_cpf.length==11){
      ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
      ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
      //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
      ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/ , "$1-$2"); //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
      
      var valorValido = document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value = ao_cpf;
     }else{
      alert("CPF invalido");
     }
 
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnBlur="ValidaCPF();"/>
```

> o X da questão passa pela exclusão de qualquer digito que não seja numero e testar se retorna 11 caracteres, o que supõe que foi inserido um cpf valido porém sem a formatação esperada.

Answer (score 1):

veja se funciona (aproveitei parte do código do amigo acima):

**JavaScript:**

```
function formatar(mascara, documento){
  var i = documento.value.length;
    if(i < 14){
      var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
      var texto = mascara.substring(i);
      if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
            documento.value += texto.substring(0,1);
      }

      if(i >= 11){
          var ao_cpf=document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value;
              ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /\D/g , "");
            ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
            ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d)/ , "$1.$2"); //Coloca um ponto entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
            //de novo (para o segundo bloco de números)
            ao_cpf = ao_cpf.replace( /(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/ , "$1-$2"); //Coloca um hífen entre o terceiro e o quarto dígitos
            var valorValido = document.getElementById("ao_cpf").value = ao_cpf;
      }
    }

}
```

**Input:**

```
<input type="text" name="ao_cpf" id="ao_cpf" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" onMouseOut="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" onKeyUp="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" />
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qz19ou7g/1/